# Plot a curve between two points in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, geometry, curves

Given a set of points, say (10, 10) and (50, 10), how can I plot a curve between them? My geometry is a bit rusty and I'm not sure of which canvas method to use (arc(), quadradicCurveTo(), etc..).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It depends on what kind of curve you want. Generally a curve is defined by more than two points.

Comment: @hobberwickey, I guess I'm not sure exactly what type of curve I need. I'd like to fill up as height as possible. e.g. height of canvas = 500, start_x = 0, start_y = 0, end_x = 50, end_y = 0, midpoint_x = 25, midpoint_y = 500;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a lot of different options depending on what you want to curve to look like, but this will basically make the two points part of an ellipse

```
function curveBetweenPoints(startX, startY, endX, endY, ctx){
    var cp1 = {
        x: startX,
        y: ctx.canvas.height - ((ctx.canvas.height - startY) / 2)
    };

    var cp2 = {
        x: startX + ((endX - startX) / 4),
        y: ctx.canvas.height
    };

    var cp3 = {
       x: endX - ((endX - startX) / 4),
       y: ctx.canvas.height
    }

    var cp4 = {
       x: endX,
       y: ctx.canvas.height - ((ctx.canvas.height - endY) / 2)
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, (endX - startX) / 2, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp3.x, cp3.y, cp4.x, cp4.y, endX, endY);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Tested this in Chrome/Firefox/Safari and it doesn't actually. The midpoint ends up somewhere towards the bottom of the canvas

Comment: well, if its an ellipse it should probably be at a midpoint of the maximum radius from the center point. When I ran your code, the line curves up slightly on both ends, then nose dives down and to the left in a kind of squiggle.

Comment: Fixed it, now it's a smoother curve, http://jsfiddle.net/e9qAH/2/. It's basically two quarters of two different ellipses stuck together. I don't know the math to make a continuous bezier that fills the available height of the canvas, or a quadratic curve that intersects two given points in a plane.